# XY matrix tampering with footnote counter

Tags: xy-pic

Typesetting the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\arabic{footnote}
$$\arabic{footnote}\xymatrix{\arabic{footnote}0\overset{\arabic{footnote}\addtocounter{footnote}{+1}\arabic{footnote}}{=}\arabic{footnote}H_1(U\cup V)\ar[r]^{\partial} & H_0(U\cap V}\arabic{footnote}.$$
\arabic{footnote}\addtocounter{footnote}{+1}\arabic{footnote}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

Why does the `footnote` counter change inside the `xymatrix` and then in the `\overset`?

Comment: The text in the first argument of `\overset` is processed more than once. Just for curiosity, do you really mean having footnote markers in an `\xymatrix`?

Comment: Yes I do. I want to make a note about the equality in the `\xymatrix` wothout having to restate it, so I puto the marker on the = sign. Why is the text inside the first argument of `\overset` processed more than once and how does that make the marker increase? For completeness' sake, I've found a temporary solution by putting the value of `footnote` in another counter and modifying `footnote` with that counter inside the `\overset`, but I'd still like to know why that happens and if there is a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't. Your readers will be grateful.

Comment: I don't see why. In any case, even if I wasn't going to do that I would want to know why this strange thing happens. So could you answer my question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to avoid footnotes in math.

Your example can be reduced and shows that `xy` typesets each cell multiple times, precisely three:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{test}
\newcommand{\dotest}{\stepcounter{test}}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{{}\dotest\thetest \ar[r] & X}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can obviate to this problem by detaching footnotes from the `\xymatrix`. The `\xyfootnote` command mustn't go inside `\[..\]`, because `amsmath` doesn't allow multiple `\label` commands in the same equation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\xyfootnote}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{footnote}\label{#1}%
  \footnotetext{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\xyfootnotemark}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fnequal}[1]{\overset{\text{(\ref{#1})}}{=}}

\begin{document}

\xyfootnote{testA}{This is the text of the first footnote}%
\xyfootnote{testB}{This is the text of the second footnote}%
\[
\xymatrix{A\fnequal{testA}B \ar[r] & X\xyfootnotemark{testB}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It might be preferred to have `\xyfootnote` inside `\[...\]`; for this, do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyfootnote}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{footnote}\ltx@label{#1}%
  \footnotetext{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\xyfootnotemark}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fnequal}[1]{\overset{\text{(\ref{#1})}}{=}}

\begin{document}

\[
\xyfootnote{testA}{This is the text of the first footnote}%
\xyfootnote{testB}{This is the text of the second footnote}%
\xymatrix{A\fnequal{testA}B \ar[r] & X\xyfootnotemark{testB}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK. Any idea why XYpic does that? I mean, why should it typeset everything three times?

Comment: And besides, if it is typeset three times, I would at.most expect a 0 to become.a 3, forgetting that I only used an `\arabic{footnote}` which as far as I know shouldn't i.crease the counter, but I surely wouldn't expect to get a 1 out of a 0, which is.what happens. I've accepted the answer because it shows a solution that seems to.work, though I haven't tried it yet, but the theoretical part still has problems,.as I just pointed out. Maybe I should.lokk.at the definition of `\xymatrix`. In any case why does the counter increase.without me.telling it to.in any way?

Comment: Moreover, if everything is typeset thrice, when I _do_ use `\addtocounter{footnote}{+1}` I should get three increases, shouldn't I? Which is not what happens because the 2 becomes a 3, just as it should. That's strange, isn't it?

Comment: @MickG No, because you had `\thefootnote`; one should go into the internals of `xy` in order to see what really happens. What's certain is that all cells are typeset three times, at the least, for measuring them and doing other bookkeeping. If a cell contains `\addtocounter`, the instruction is performed three times.